# Rails - How can I detect if the content_for content was provided?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb

I want to detect if content was provided for content_for tag in my template, and if not fall back to default value:

```
<title>
  <% if content_is_provided -%>
    <%= yield :title -%>
  <% else -%>
    404 - Page Unknown
  <% end -%>
</title>
```

Any easy way to detect this? I tried `<% if :title -%>` but that didn't do much. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can streamline the code further:

```
def content_exists?(name)
  return instance_variable_get("@content_for_#{name}")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<title>
  <%= yield :title || "404 - Page Unknown" -%>
</title>
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work for me (no title is echoed). I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

In an old Rails 2.1.1,

```rb
<%= (yield :title) || default_title %>
```

is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

After digging in the content_for code a bit, I found a working solution by creating a helper method:

```
def content_exists?(name)
  return true if instance_variable_get("@content_for_#{name}")
  return false # I like to be explicit :)
end
```

and in the view:

```
<% if content_exists?(:title)-%>
  <%= yield :title %>
<% else -%>
  404 - Page Unknown
<% end -%>
```

This seems to be working, for now (Rails 2.3.5).

Answer (score 1):

One more way

'common/top_status') %>